Need to Delete all folders but two via command line
I am working on deleting folders that are different from two set versions.  This is in PDQ and would like to not use a full batch file so I can utilize the variables in PDQ. I was using just the following command.
FOR /d %%a IN ("SourceDIR\*") DO IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="*SAVESubdirectory@(PDQVariable)*" RD /S /Q "%%a"

I was wondering if the below would keep both directories while deleting any other directories.
FOR /d %%a IN ("SourceDIR\*") DO IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="*SAVESubdirectory1@(PDQVariable1)*" OR "SAVESubdirectory2@(PDQVariable2)*" RD /S /Q "%%a"

However, I received the error that OR is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
I just need to know how to get that second directory into the string so I can delete all folders but those two.

Can you test that on a dummy folder?

Yeah it did fail.  I'm trying to fine a way to use this for two folders instead of just one.  I just need to know how to add the second folder.

Add that information to your question to make it better. Knowing that you've tested is really good info, knowing the outcome of those tests and what still needs to be accomplished is even better. Use the EDIT button as often as you like and keep improving the question until someone gets you the good info you're seeking.

You could use something like this, assuming folder1 and folder2 are the names contained in the folders you don't want to delete:
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /ad "*SourceDIR\*" ^|find /i /v "folder1" ^|find /i /v "folder2"') do rd /q /s "SourceDIR\%a"


I will give that a try and report back shortly.  Thank you!

That is exactly what I needed!  It works great.  Thank you so much!
